# How to extend class in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

i want to used a function on the extend class but i cant call it

```
import testCase.mainClass;    
public class teamMemberValidation extends mainClass{

mainClass mClass = new mainClass;

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest(){
    String exePath = "/home/dev/chromedriver";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize(); // Maximize window
    timeImp(5);
    driver.get("http://sample/sight");

    mClass.test("Hello World");
}

@AfterTest
public void afterTest() {
    //driver.close();
}   
}

public class mainClass {

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest(){
    String exePath = "/home/dev/chromedriver";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize(); // Maximize window
    timeImp(5);
    driver.get("http://sample/sight");

    mClass.test("Hello World");
}

public void test(String text){
    System.out.print(text);
}

@AfterTest
public void afterTest() {
    //driver.close();
}   
}
```

Comment: Which function do you want to extends??

Comment: i want to extend mainClass to teamMemberValidation and use the test funtion inside the  beforeTest function of teamMemberValidation

Comment: No, you can't extends test function, you need to create simple class instead of testNG class and then you can extends this simple class in your test class..:)